# Installing GTK+ directly from R

Tags: r, gtk, gwidgets

I have downloaded the installation file directly from the ftp site. How do I trigger the installation directly from R using the downloaded zip file of GTK?
I cant do it directly through RGtk because the company firewall doesn't allow the pcs to.

Comment: What OS are you on? Is the file binary?

Comment: I'm on windows. I'm not sure if I know exactly whats a binary file. The zip has folders with .h .exe .dll .sh
This is the link to the file : ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/binaries/win32/gtk+/2.22/gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101227_win32.zip

Comment: How would you install this "by hand"? By running the .exe file?